# Form api: Combine two text fields into a div?

Tags: 7, forms, theming

Using the form api is it possible to combine two text fields onto the same row?

E.g. form

```
<?php
function foo_form($form, $form_state) {
  $form = array();

  $form['range'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
 );

  $form['range']['min'] = array(
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#title' => 'Address'
  ),
  $form['range']['address2'] = array(
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#title' => 'Address'
  )
  // ...
  return $form;
}
```

Desired output

```
<div>
  <h2>Range</h2>
  <input name="min" /> to <input name="max" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<?php
function foo_form($form, $form_state) {
  $form = array();

  $form['range'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#prefix' => '<div class="myclass">',
 );

  $form['range']['min'] = array(
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#title' => 'Address'
  ),
  $form['range']['address2'] = array(
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#title' => 'Address'
     '#suffix' => '</div>',
  )
  // Remaining code
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why didn't you add the suffix to the fieldset, instead of the last control in the group?

Comment: Note: If you put an opening <div> prefix on the wrapper and suffix on another element you will likely break ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Its better use css to align two inline . Find out the wrapper div id, then apply this css

```
WRAPPER_ID {
  display :inline; // or try inline-block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This Drupal Stackexchange answer regarding Horizontal Form Elements](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/horizontal-form-elements) answered earlier may be beneficial to you. I typically do the same thing with a wrapper div, but did not know about the `container-inline` class.

Answer (score -1):

There's a module that may be of assistance: [Field Collection (7.x)](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection)

Comment: This question is specifically about the FAPI.  Also, Field Collection (which is awesome btw) would solely for this would add a whole layer of complexity that isn't required.  If you're building forms with the UI then [Field Group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) would be a much better option.